# Only send post/get if form values has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to prevent multiple ajax calls (user holds enter key down or multi presses submit or other)

I'm thinking, the best way is to use a var with the previous form post values and compare them at each click/submit.. Is it the same? : Then do nothing

But I don't know how to go about it

Here is my javascript/jquery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    $theform = $(this);

    $.ajax({
    url: 'validate.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    data: $theform.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        if (data=='' || !data || data=='-' || data=='ok') {
            // something went wrong (ajax/response) or everything is ok, submit and continue to php validation
            $('input[type=submit]',$theform).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $theform.unbind('submit').submit();
        } else {
            // ajax/response is ok, but user input did not validate, so don't submit
            console.log('test');
            $('#jserrors').html('<p class="error">' + data + '</p>');
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
        // something went wrong (ajax), submit and continue to php validation
        $('input[type=submit]',$theform).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $theform.unbind('submit').submit();
    }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very creative with naming vars here:

```
var serial_token = '';

$('form').submit(function() {

    $theform = $(this);

    if ($(this).serialize() === serial_token) {
        console.log('multiple ajax call detected');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        serial_token = $(this).serialize();
    }


    $.ajax({
    url: 'validate.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    data: $theform.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        if (data=='' || !data || data=='-' || data=='ok') {
            // something went wrong (ajax/response) or everything is ok, submit and continue to php validation
            $('input[type=submit]',$theform).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $theform.unbind('submit').submit();
        } else {
            // ajax/response is ok, but user input did not validate, so don't submit
            console.log('test');
            $('#jserrors').html('<p class="error">' + data + '</p>');
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
        // something went wrong (ajax), submit and continue to php validation
        $('input[type=submit]',$theform).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $theform.unbind('submit').submit();
    }
    });

    return false;

});
```

You could combine this with a timeout/interval function which aborts the submit, but the code above should just compare the data in the form

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of submit button, just add a class 'disabled' to it when you start the ajax call, and check if it is present before trying to make the call. Remove the class when the server gives a response. Something like:

```
...

$theform = $(this);
$button = $theform.find('input[type=submit]');

if ($button.hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
}

$button.addClass('disabled');

 $.ajax({

     ....

     },
     complete: function () {
         $button.removeClass('disabled');
     }
 });

...
```